# How do I pass decimals to stored procedure without decimals rounding?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters, user-defined-types

Hey I have a stored procedure that I pass parameters to. The parameter type is "structured" and uses a user defined table type. The table type looks something like this cut down version.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.LineItem_TYPE AS TABLE
(

UnitTrade numeric (22,4), 
TotalBuy numeric (22,4),
TotalSell numeric (22,4), 
GrossProfit numeric (22,4), 
QuoteReference varchar (255)
)
```

The actual table matches this (the same precision ect.) but rounds the decimal values. What is wrong SQL gurus?

Comment: please show offending code...

Answer (score 0):

Check how you are using it against this sample.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.LineItem_TYPE AS TABLE
(
    UnitTrade numeric (22,4), 
    TotalBuy numeric (22,4),
    TotalSell numeric (22,4), 
    GrossProfit numeric (22,4), 
    QuoteReference varchar (255)
);
GO
CREATE TABLE LineItem
(
    UnitTrade numeric (22,4), 
    TotalBuy numeric (22,4),
    TotalSell numeric (22,4), 
    GrossProfit numeric (22,4), 
    QuoteReference varchar (255)
);
GO
create proc dbo.uspInsertLineItem
@li dbo.LineItem_TYPE READONLY
AS
    set nocount on;
    insert LineItem
    select *
    FROM @li;
GO
declare @li dbo.LineItem_TYPE;
insert @li select
1.23451234,123456789.1111,10.50,1,'Quote1' union all select
999999999999999999.9999,1.1,2.2,null,'Quote1';
exec dbo.uspInsertLineItem @li;
GO
select * from LineItem

------- results

UnitTrade                TotalBuy        TotalSell  GrossProfit  QuoteReference
------------------------ --------------- ---------- ------------ ---------------
1.2345 ****              123456789.1111  10.5000    1.0000       Quote1
999999999999999999.9999  1.1000          2.2000     NULL         Quote1
```

You can see that all the numerics are faithfully stored to the correct number of decimal places, except the singular one marked ****.  We put `1.23451234` into @li, which because it is a `numeric(22,4)` was already 1.2345 as soon as it entered the user-type.  See this:

```
declare @li dbo.LineItem_TYPE;
insert @li (UnitTrade)
select 1.23451234;
select UnitTrade from @li

--------- result

UnitTrade
---------------------------------------
1.2345
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try variable type `float` instead of `numeric`.

Also make sure that you pass the `decimal`/`double` variables to the stored procedure from your program.